# Derivative of a quadratic form - help

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I have this matrix: $\pi^T \sigma \sigma^T \pi$, where $\pi$ is (n x 1) and $\sigma$ is (n x d). If I take the derivative with respect to $\pi$, I should get a (n x 1) vector, right?

I was reading about derivatives of quadratic forms (namely [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075887/derivative-of-a-quadratic-form) and [here](http://michael.orlitzky.com/articles/the_derivative_of_a_quadratic_form.php) ), and couldn't figure out exactly what the derivative would be.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:\pi\rightarrow \pi ^T\sigma\sigma^T\pi$. The derivative is $Df_{\pi}:h\in \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow 2h^T\sigma\sigma^T\pi$ and the gradient is $\nabla(f)(\pi)=2\sigma\sigma^T\pi$.